# Weight in Relationship Property Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, weighted-graph

I want to add weight in relationship property. Weight are counted from this code:

```
MATCH (n1)-[r1:NEXT]->(n2)
DELETE r1
RETURN n1, n2, apoc.create.vRelationship(n1, 'WEIGHT', {weight:count(r1)}, n2);
```

But the "WEIGHT" doesn't appear in the property of r1
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't worked with `apoc` so I answer your question with **pure cypher**:

```
MATCH (n1)-[r1:NEXT]-(n2)
WITH count(r1) as count_rel, n
CREATE (n1)-[:WEIGHT {weight: count_rel}]->(n2)
```

If you delete r1 relation it would create `WEIGHT` relation for every `NEXT` relation. For handling this problem you can remove `NEXT` relation in **another query after this one**, unfortunately I don't know how merge these 2 query in one query :(. **Hope someone help to improve this answer :).**

Answer (score 0):

This APOC method creates a virtual relationship - do notice the v in apoc.create.**v**Relationship

https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.vRelationship/
apoc.create.vRelationship(nodeFrom,'KNOWS',{key:value,…​}, nodeTo) returns a **virtual** relationship